# Swift/Firebase change value from tableview

Tags: swift, firebase, tableview, firebase-realtime-database

Basically I am experiencing some difficulties trying to change the value from Firebase in a tableview. I am currently trying to make a Facebook-post-like feature, allowing people to like your post. However, I am not quite sure how I would proceed with this. I want to give the user the ability to like each post, and then save the previous likes + the like that was given, and update it in firebase. As of right now, I only have the code to display each post, and also the @IBAction from the button(Like button).

I am not sure how I would manage to access each specific post through only the table view, using indexPath.row(?). Here is the code I have so far:

Post edit:

So basically I have a tableview, containing a table view cell that displays the amount of likes each post has. To do this, I have this code in my viewDidLoad(), to just fetch the data from Firebase:

```
ref.childByAppendingPath("posts").queryOrderedByChild("timeRegistered").observeEventType(FEventType.ChildAdded) { (snapshot:FDataSnapshot!) in

        var dict = [String:String]()
        dict["keys"] = snapshot.key as? String
        dict["votes"] = snapshot.value["likes"] as? String
        self.posts.append(dict)

        self.tableView.reloadData()


    }
```

Just to mention, this code works, by using this code in the cellForRowAtIndexPath: `cell.textLabel!.text = String(posts[indexPath.row]["names"]!)`

However, I thought that the code that I used in viewDidLoad (.ChildAdded function) would work with ChildChanged as well, so this is what I came up with:

```
ref.childByAppendingPath("posts").queryOrderedByChild("timeRegistered").observeEventType(FEventType.ChildChanged) { (snapshot:FDataSnapshot!) in

        var dict = [String:String]()
        dict["keys"] = snapshot.key as? String
        dict["votes"] = snapshot.value["votes"] as? String
        self.posts.append(dict)

        self.tableView.reloadData()


    }
```

Unfortunately, it looks like the tableview just displays the new value (the value changed from an IBAction, I'll provide this code as well.) - while the old value just stays there. This is the code for changing value:

```
var key = posts[1]["keys"]
    ref.childByAppendingPath("posts").childByAppendingPath(key!).updateChildValues(["name":"Test name"])
    tableView.reloadData()
```

Still trying to figure out a better way of changing the exact value, through index - but that is not the case now (therefore posts[1]["keys"]). Do you seem to understand what the problem is?

To sum up: I want to click a button inside a table view cell, and adding a like to the specific post, and updating the total count in real time.

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're trying to do; and also, what's the interface? Is 'votes' and 'likes' the same thing? One simple solution would be a little + button on each row and when the user clicks the +, that increments the votes/likes. You know what row it is via clickedRow or perhaps have custom cell that handles the click.

Comment: So basically I want to add the 'likes'-function, as you can call it - and I want it to update the records immediately after pressing 'like' (old likes+1 new like).

Comment: I think so... Don't over complicate it. Just have an IBAction that responds to clicking a + button. Determine which row was clicked, then get the current likes from your array of posts[clickedRow], increment likes and then update the value in Firebase via the firebase Key for that row and the child node likes.setValue(votes).

Comment: @Jay That's basically what I am trying to achieve. However, I am struggling with updating the values in the tableview. I am trying to update this data using the Firebase ChildChanged function, like this:
`ref.childByAppendingPath("names").queryOrderedByChild("timeRegistered").observeEventType(FEventType.ChildChanged) { (snapshot:FDataSnapshot!) in
            var dict = [String:String]()
            dict["keys"] = snapshot.key as? String
            dict["votes"] = snapshot.value["votes"] as? String
            self.posts.append(dict)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }`

Comment: @Jay What seems to be the problem though, is that the old value still displays, and the new value displays in a new table view cell. Do you know how I can avoid this?

Comment: Please don't post code in comments, it's super hard to read - update your question with formatted code. If the old value displays and the new value is in a different cell, it sounds like the wrong cell is being updated. Try stepping through the code; verify the array row being updated was the one that was clicked on - the array index should match the row. Then when updating the value in the array, make sure it sticks. Make sure to reloadTableview. Also take a look at firebase to see if you are accidentally writing out a new row as it should be updating an existing one and no events should fire

Comment: @Jay Sorry for slow update, my internet was down for a while. However, I have now provided you with more code, and more details. I hope this helps, and I really hope you can figure out the problem I am experiencing.

Comment: Ah - your ChildChanged event is one issue. When a child is changed your code is appending it onto the array, creating a duplicate child with different data. What you should be doing is determining which child it is, get that dictionary from the array and update the values with the new values. I also note your dictionary has a key called keys. You should probably rename that to singular key since it's only one. Just to avoid confusion later.

Comment: @Jay Do you have any suggestion on how I would determine that? I mean, there is literally no possible way I could determine the old value, and I don't know how I would determine it by index, and I am sorting the data in descending order by 'timeRegistered'. I thought of maybe just grab the key, but again - that is of no use, as it would not impact the display at all - because I am fetching and displaying the data through ChildAdded ("name")-value. (There is no way I could use that key, as keys and post'names' are stored separately.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple answers so here's a few things:

The ChildChanged event is one issue. When a child is changed your code is appending it onto the array, creating a duplicate child with different data. What you should be doing is determining which child it is, get that dictionary from the array and update the values with the new values.

The followup comments asks 'how do you do that'.

There are a number of ways to get to it depending on how you want to store your data. I'll give two examples:

Suppose you have a Post structure (object) that contains information about each post. This is a way better solution than working with dictionaries. The structure will contain the firebase key, the msg and the uid of the user that made the post and you store those Posts in a postsArray

```
struct Post {
    var firebaseKey : String?
    var msg: String?
    var uid: String?

    init(aFirebaseKey: String, aMsg: String, aUid: String ) {
        self.firebaseKey = aFirebaseKey
        self.msg = aMsg
        self.uid = aUid
    }
}

var postsArray = [Post]()
```

and suppose you are observing the posts node for changes:

```
postsRef.observeEventType(.ChildChanged, withBlock: { snapshot in
  let changedKey = snapshot.key //the firebase key
  if let index = self.postsArray.indexOf({$0.firebaseKey == changedKey}) {
    print(index) //index is the index of the Post in the array
    let changedPost = self.postsArray[index]
    //update the values
    self.tableView.reloadData
}
```

and to make it complete, the initial loading of the posts

```
postsRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
  for child in snapshot.children {

    let theKey = child.key as String
    let theMsg = child.value["msg"] as! String
    let theUid = child.value["user"] as! String

    let p = Post(aFirebaseKey: theKey, aMsg: theMsg, aUid: theUid)

    self.postsArray.append(p)              
  }
})
```

Another option is to keep side by side arrays.

```
keysArray[String]()
valuesArray[Dictionary]()
```

Using similar code, in the childChanged event get the firebase key and then simply find that key within the keysArray which will return it's index. Then use the returned index to get the values from the valuesArray; update them and reloadTableview.

```
let index= keysArray.indexOf(firebaseKey) //get the index for this post

let postToUpdate = self.valuesArray[index]
//update the Post
```

Of course when initially loading the arrays, you put the keys in the keysArray and the values in the valuesArray